# How to send image data along with other product data to api? react & django

Tags: reactjs

I have the following information about a product and its variants:

```
{
 name: "",
 description: "",
 category: "",
 brand: "",
 colors: {
 red: {
    images: [img1, img2]
    variants: [ 
   {
     size: "23"
     stock:  23,
     barcode: ""
     price: 200
    },
    {
     size: "24"
     stock:  24,
     barcode: ""
     price: 300
    },
 {
     size: "25"
     stock:  25,
     barcode: ""
     price: 400
    },
 ]
},

 green: {
    images: [img1, img2]
    variants: [ 
   {
     size: "23"
     stock:  23,
     barcode: ""
     price: 200
    },
    {
     size: "24"
     stock:  24,
     barcode: ""
     price: 300
    },
 {
     size: "25"
     stock:  25,
     barcode: ""
     price: 400
    },
 ]
}


}
```

as you can see each color will have different multiple images uploaded. Initially, I thought I could just send this data as json but quickly realized I wouldn't be able to do that for images. Now I'm not sure how can I send the images and maintain the relation they have with colors. Any help or suggestion is appreciated!

Comment: did you tried to do it with base64 encoding for the images

Comment: @ZhivkoNikolov I found out that base64 could have some performance issues if the images are large. Is that correct? and is there an alternative?

Comment: correct, but you can compress the image if the ultra high quality is not an issue

Comment: @ZhivkoNikolov do you know of an alternative?

Comment: for this case no sorry :\